# How print the URL from link-to?

Tags: ember.js

Have a way to get the URL from `link-to` and print that?

```
{{#link-to "route.name" params}}
  https://example.com/route/name/params {{!-- Change this with the URL of link-to  --}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own component extending `LinkComponent` and exposing its `href` property:

component.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.LinkComponent.extend({
});
```

template.hbs:

```
{{#if hasBlock}}
   {{yield href}}
{{else}}
   {{linkTitle}}
{{/if}}
```

And then use it:

```
{{#my-link "route.name" as |href| }}
  {{href}}
{{/my-link}}
```

[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b8c8d3a9235cde901a29969a0fedeb29)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ember-href-to](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to) addon. and use `href-to` helper to get the URL.